# jquery hover works for only certain divs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

i have jquery carousel where i am trying to implement hover for all the divs 
but it works for only certain divs can you tell me why its not working for other divs...
when you click green and red button you can see the carousel movement....

http://jsfiddle.net/9Dr7T/14/

providing my js code below

```
$(".specialHover").hover(
  function () {
        //  $("<div class='cta'>add image</div>").click(function() {
    $("<div class='cta'>add image</div>").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().unbind("hover").children("img").attr("src", "http://www.onlinegrocerystore.co.uk/images/goodfood.jpg");
        $(this).remove();
    }).appendTo(this);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("div:last").remove();
  }
);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9Dr7T/14/embedded/result/ you can see the result here... this img tag does not show the add image div <img src="" data-lazyload="" width="200" height="262" alt="5" title="iPhone Life" class="cover lazy">

Answer (score 0):

Well simply comment the last line of your code as following:

```
$(".specialHover").hover(
  function () {
        //  $("<div class='cta'>add image</div>").click(function() {
    $("<div class='cta'>add image</div>").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().unbind("hover").children("img").attr("src", "http://www.onlinegrocerystore.co.uk/images/goodfood.jpg");
        $(this).remove();
    }).appendTo(this);
  }, 
  function () {
    //$(this).find("div:last").remove();
  }
);
```

**//$(this).find("div:last").remove();**

Comment: @SEMSEM: thanks for your reply but later when i come out of the div it should disappear it should not stay permanent http://jsfiddle.net/9Dr7T/17/embedded/result/

Comment: By this way you have to use mouseout event to hide it or try to make or use another selector.

Comment: can you update it in the fiddle...i am not getting it....http://jsfiddle.net/9Dr7T/17/

Comment: Could you able to reduce height of divs from 5 to 9? Your problem seems to be render of "add image" out of the view! or make "add image" to be rendered at the top.

Comment: @semsem: can you tell me should I need to reduce the height in the css or jquery

Comment: @user1813724 Indeed you should increase the height of the container that contains your divs or reduce your divs via css.